# responsive site breaks when chrome dev tool is opened

Tags: css

I'm designing a site and making it responsive. I have added media queries but when I open chrome dev tool at the break point of `min-width: 320px`, the site breaks(Basically all the css styles disappears). I have the same issue when I zoom the window size to 150%, the styles on all the screen width-320px, 481px,641px etc.. disappears (this is without opening the chrome dev tool).  How to fix this?

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px){
  //when chrome dev tool is opened, none of the styles in this breakpoint get applied
}
```

Comment: You need to have rules that apply outside of your media query too because any rule defined in it will not be effective when the width is lower than 320px. See it as default rules.

Comment: what about 150% screen zoom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**On zoom level**: you are only supposed to code at zoom level 100%.

Whatever is at any other zoom level is not under you control, it behaves differently in almost every browser and you have no means to determine the zoom level cross-browser/cross-device (and in some you can't determine it at all or, or they might even belying about it).

The whole point of zooming is to take control away from you or the website and give it to the user. They have the choice of seeing the content zoomed in or out, willingly giving up on *"pixel-perfect"* quality in favor of either readability or birds' eye view. Do not change your zoom level when designing. If you do, your design will fail miserably on many device/browser combinations.

Even more so, browsers zooming mechanism is based on the conventional assumption your page is "normal" at zoom level 100%. If you change that, you will not only break your website at `100%` but, most likely, you will also break it at other zoom levels, which is a major hit on accessibility and usability. Do not do it.

In addition, most users expect and do not mind things not looking perfect in a zoomed in/out page but, at the same time, they expect pixel-perfect quality at zoom level 100%. Just like yourself. ツ

---

**On @media queries**: all code is convention. When you tell the browser to do something, it does it. By placing your rules inside a

```
@media (min-width: 320px) {
  // code here
}
```

you are telling the browser: only apply these rules if the device's declared width in CSS pixels is larger than `320px`. If you also want those applied when the screen is smaller than `320px` either remove or modify your media query.

---

Here's an example of applying responsiveness using mobile first approach (used by most modern frameworks):

```css
/* 
 * general rules applying for all cases 
 */

.example { color: red; }
.example:before {content: 'general (applies everywhere, unless overridden)'}

@media (min-width:576px) {
  /* applying only from $sm up */
  .example { color: blue; }
  .example:before {content: '$sm (applies above 576px)'}
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
  /* applying only from $md up  */
  .example { color: green; }
  .example:before {content: '$md (applies above 768px)'}
}

@media (min-width:992px) {
  /* applying only from $lg up */
  .example { color: gray; }
  .example:before {content: '$lg (applies above 992px)'}
   
}

@media (min-width:1200px) {
  /* applying only from $lg up */
  .example { color: black; }
  .example:before {content: '$xl (applies above 1200px)'}
}
```

```html
<h1 class="example"></h1>
<ul>
<li style="color:red">general</li>
<li style="color:blue">$sm</li>
<li style="color:green">$md</li>
<li style="color:gray">$lg</li>
<li style="color:black">$xl</li>
</ul>
```

Note `@media` does not increase the specificity. It only limits when the code is taken into consideration and when not.

I've also seen people always writing their `@media` queries using `only screen` just because they've seen it in the examples, not knowing what it does and afraid not to break stuff, only to later ask why their styles do not apply to print. The principle is the same:

- place any styles you want applied on both `screen` and `print` outside of any `@media` query
- place each styles you want to specifically apply to either `screen` or `print` inside a `@media` query with `only screen` or `only print`.

While `print` and `screen` are the most common media types, there are a few others: `braille`, `embossed`, `handheld`, `projection`, `speech`, `tty`, `tv`. Default value of media type is `all`.

Comment: I used this eventually: `@media only screen and (min-width: 10px) and (max-width: 319px) { }`

Comment: @deke, updated with a best practice example. Also, only use `only screen` if you don't want your styles to apply to print. If you want them to apply to both, don't use `only screen`. Run the example in full-screen and resize your browser.